# React: How to persist the data when refreshing? The data is retrieved from an API when rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is my Component in the main App JS file:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        myValue: 'some value'
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // retrieve the data from an API and save them into state
        myApi.getData().then((myData) => {
            this.setState(myData);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // render the website corresponding to the retrieved data (state)
        )
    }
}
```

After rendering, the `state` (data) is changed.
When refreshing the website, the state is set to the newly retrieved data from the API.

---

- How can I persist the changed data after refreshing? 
  (Don't fetch new data when refreshing?)

Comment: In your `componentDidMount`, check your if state value contains anything. If it doesn't, check your local storage for a cookie. If a cookie doesn't exist, call your `getData` and store that value as part of your cookie. If it does, read the data from the cookie and use that as part of your new state

Comment: This might help explain how to use local storage with React: https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29497367/691711 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144565/691711

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is the easiest solution for your use case.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        myValue: 'some value'
    }

    const myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));

    if(myData) return;

    api.getData().then((myData) => {
        localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(myData));
        this.setState(myData);
    });

    render() {
        return (
            // render the website corresponding to the retrieved data (state)
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myData: 'some value'
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let myDataFromSessionStorage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("myData"))
    if (!myDataFromSessionStorage) {
      // retrieve the data from an API and save them into state
      myApi.getData().then((myData) => {
        this.setState({
          myData,
        }, () => {
          //Callback which will be executed once the state has been set
          sessionStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(myData))
        });
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        myData: myDataFromSessionStorage,
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // render the website corresponding to the retrieved data (state)
    )
  }
}
```

Use localstorage to keep the data even when the browser is reopened.